# how to add "Empty Module" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, module, ide, android-studio

I am trying to add AndEngine to my Android Project using the tutorial here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fcSowvlKMqfTjM9r1mMP48KEhWbkJZGBDR5duFg4QYc/edit

I am stuck at Step #6 in the tutorial, unable to see the "Empty Module" option in my Android Studio Envt. (Version 0.4.0)

[image: Screenshot of Selecting 'Empty Module' option in Android Studio - how to find this?]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the AndEngine module inside your project directory and then configure your build.gradle and settings.gradle to include it in to dependencies  like

```
 ----YOUR_PROJECT
   ---AndEngine
     --res
     --src
     -- .....
     -- build.gradle
   ---YOUR_MODULE
     --res
     --src
     --build.gradle (no : A)
 ----settings.gradle
```

build.gradle (No. A) file

```
  dependencies {
       compile project(':AndEngine')
   }
```

settings.gradle :

```
   include ':YOUR_MODULE'
   include ':AndEngine'
```

As Observed AndEngine is not moved to gradle yet, In that case download create jar using ant or eclipse.

The create a libs folder inside your Project

```
  ----YOUR_PROJECT

   ---YOUR_MODULE
     --libs
       -AndEngine.jar
     --res
     --src
     --build.gradle (no : A)
 ----settings.gradle
```

Now go to File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + green button > File Dependency > select AndEngine.jar and press OK

You will see these lines will be automatically added in your build.gradle file inside dependencies, you can add this manually as well no difference.

```
      compile files('libs/AndEngine.jar')
```

Comment: That's AndEngine, not AppEngine

Comment: @pyus13 I followed your instructions exactly, I get this error "Failed to notify project evaluation listener"... here is my screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/5mcvpvsar/

Comment: @user1406716 It seems your AndEngine is not a gradle project.AFAIK you can not add a non gradle project like this better to make and jar using ant then follow Scott's approach.

Answer (score 1):

Their instructions were written for Android Studio 0.2; this dialog has changed since then. They have some hasty steps for 0.3 which should work; I've amended them:

- Download andengine.jar (Google it, there is no official download)
- Create your own libs folder in your project
- Copy andengine.jar into this folder
- File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + button > File Dependency > select andengine.jar

If you need more help, there are many other answers on SO on how to add a jar library to Android Studio; they vary a little bit based on what version of Android Studio they're written for, but they should help you out. Many of them have you modify your `build.gradle` file directly; the UI steps above accomplish much the same thing and make the edits on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to add the dependency but even when I try to import AndEngine as "org.andengine...", it does not auto-complete/work. So still looking for a solution... :)
(I have synced gradle files with project too)

Comment: See if clicking on the Sync Project with Gradle Files button helps that.

Comment: I click on it after every change made to any gradle file, still no luck :(. This is disappointing, I guess people AndEngine community continues to use Eclipse?? :(

Comment: In its current state Android Studio requires some good troubleshooting skills to work around its bugs, so I think a lot of people are staying on Eclipse until it improves. In your case, we know a lot of users are having problems with getting libraries imported, and we're working on a number of fronts. One bug we're tracking is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64508 which I think you can work around by doing a clean build after adding a dependency. Does this help you?

Comment: It didnt :(. I am going to install Eclipse and try this, especially since I want to experiment with AndEngine for now. Thanks for the help. Since I am not able to mark your response as an answer, but it has helped, i am going to +1 it, thank you again.