# Unable to add AndEngine to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, andengine, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to almost 2 days to add AndEngine to Android Studio but unable to do so. I tried the following two methods, neither worked.

**1st Try**
I download the AndEngine code from [GitHub Link](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) -- this is NOT a Gradle Project

and tried to add it to my Android Studio build.gradle and settings.gradle, but i get this error, my screenshot: https://postimg.cc/image/5mcvpvsar/
(I think I am getting this error because AndEngine is not a gradle project - HOW TO MAKE IT A GRADLE PROJECT??)

**2nd Try**
I have also tried adding the andengine.jar (file I just googled for) in /libs folder and do right-click --> "Add as Library" but still I cannot do "import org.andengine...." in my project files.

All tutorials available online are in Eclipse, I am using Android Studio.

I am not even able to start.

**UPDATE**: Yes, I gave up using Android Studio for AndEngine! Took me 15mins to do this in Eclipse, compared to the unsuccessful weekend (which i will never get back!) I spent on Android Studio

Comment: Did you try to `git clone` andengine project add ad it as a module in Android Studio?

Comment: I did git clone and used the steps by @pyus13 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071522/how-to-add-empty-module-in-android-studio/21072949?noredirect=1#comment31701523_21072949 to add as module. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: Oh I was talking about non gradle project

Comment: I guess I need to create .jar file using Ant? May open a separate thread on that.

Comment: No you don't have to, if you have non gradle project then in project structure you can add module which in this case will be AndEngine project folder

Comment: @user1406716 I had a lot of troubles too. I posted a Q&A style post here if you want to try again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694511/how-do-i-make-a-hello-world-with-andengine-inside-android-studio-on-a-mac/27694512#27694512

Answer (score 7):

I created a tutorial for this - How to add Andengine, Andengine Tile Map, Andengine PhysicsBox2D to Android Studio 0.8.9.

Here is the link, I hope everything works - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zk2QjNiPvkj52G4qSVivEPrLfkCUVqmnCVH8TfsnER8/edit

ANDENGINE WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

Note: I am using the AnchorCenter brach and TortoiseGit to get all the files.

1. Download Andengine from github using TortoiseGit: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine
2. After the dowload  use TortoiseGit to switch to branch GLES2-AnchorCenter
3. Create new project in Android Studio
4. Create new module:
5. Select File -> New Module -> Android Library
6. Set Application name to AndEngine
7. Set Module Name to AndEngine
8. Set Package Name to org.andengine
9. Set Minimum SDK 14
10. Target SDK 19
11. Compile with 19
12. Theme None
13. Keep clicking next until module is created (no difference what you pick)
14. Enter the folder where you have downloaded Andengine, enter src/org/andengine and copy all the files inside.
15. Paste the copied files into your new module in your project src/java/org.andengine. After pasting everything remove tha MainActivity that was created on default
16. Enter the folder where you have downloaded Andengine, copy AndroidManifest and paste it into your new module (src/main)
17. Add the module to the project:
18. Select File-> Project Structure -> app-> Dependencies
19. Click the “+” button and pick “Module Dependency”
20. Select from the list your AndEngine Module
21. Check your project gradle in app folder (build.gradle) and make sure you have a line like this under dependencies - compile project(':AndEngine')

You should now be able to use AndEngine in your project

ANDENGINE TMX TILED MAP EXTENSION WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

Note: We do this the same way like with Andengine but we change a few things:

1. Download AndengineTMX from github using TortoiseGit: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
2. After the dowload  use TortoiseGit to switch to branch GLES2-AnchorCenter
3. Create new project in Android Studio
4. Create new module:
5. Select File -> New Module -> Android Library
6. Set Application name to AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
7. Set Module Name to AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
8. Set Package Name to  org.andengine.extension.tmx
9. Set Minimum SDK 14
10. Target SDK 19
11. Compile with 19
12. Theme None
13. Keep clicking next until module is created (no difference what you pick)
14. Enter the folder where you have downloaded AndengineTMX , enter src/org/andengine/extension/tmx and copy all the files inside.
15. Paste the copied files into your new module in your project src/java/org.andengine.extension.tmx. After pasting everything remove tha MainActivity that was created on default
16. Enter the folder where you have downloaded AndengineTMX, copy AndroidManifest and paste it into your new module (src/main)
17. Add the module to the project:
18. Select File-> Project Structure -> app-> Dependencies
19. Click the “+” button and pick “Module Dependency”
20. Select from the list your AndengineTMX Module
21. Check your project gradle in app folder (build.gradle) and make sure you have a line like this under dependencies - compile project(':AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension')

You should now be able to use AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension in your project.

ANDENGINE PHYSICSBOX2D WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

1. Download this file - http://d-h.st/FyC
2. Unzip the file
3. You should have 2 jar files, copy them to your project app/libs
4. Right click on andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar and select “Add as library” (or something like this)
5. Open your build.gradle in your app folder
6. Under dependencies add compile files('lib/physicsbox2d_so_files.jar')

You should now be able to use PhysicsBox2D in your project.

Answer (score 6):

I use this techique: I set this in my `settings.gradle`

```
include 'andengine'

project(':andengine').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../relative/path/to/andengine')
```

that is in the root directory of the project (I think gradle has already created it for your main project).

In AndEngine use a `build.gradle` like the following for the AndEngine project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

and add in the dependencies of your project

```
compile project(':andengine')
```

Maybe you have to close and reopen Android Studio, but normally for me this works.

BTW after have write the answer I see that someone has opened a [pull request](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/pull/227) for a gradle build file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I still cannot do "import org.andengine.*...". My setup screenshot is at: http://postimg.org/image/htzjwulqr/, am I doing it right? And Did you mean 'settings.gradle' instead of 'gradle.settings'? (In the screenshot, 'Practice' is my App files and 'AndEngine' in the file structure is from GitHub)

Comment: My settings.gradle file has this 'include ':Practice'
include ':AndEngine''

Comment: you are right, is `settings.gradle`, sorry :P BTW I edited the answer: you need also to add the `compile project(':andengine')` line in the dependencies section of your main project.

Comment: I still cannot import org.andengine.*, here's a 30s video of my setup: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_X6JX97Y-s. Sincerely appreciate if you can point out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: you have also to add the `project(':andengine').projectDir = ` part in the `settings.gradle` otherwise Android Studio could not found the library.

Comment: In settings.gradle, I am doing 'project(':AndEngine').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../AndEngine')' -- is this the correct relative path for me, folder structure screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/s7aishzcb/. Thank you very much for helping, new to gradle/library stuff here.

Comment: Probably must be `include 'AndEngine'` without colon, I don't know why. Gradle is like black magic sometimes :)

Comment: You can't have a library outside the root directory of your project, and this trickery in settings.gradle to try to get it to use that path ultimately isn't going to work.

Comment: @ScottBarta I use everyday libraries outside of the root directory

Answer (score 4):

Check out this tutorial on how to use andengine in android studio

http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.in/2014/05/settings-up-andengine-in-android-studio.html

Brief Summary of the Tutorial(Check out the full tutorial if you face any issue):

Let's assume that you already have created a project and it has default structure. First create folder named third_party in the root directory of the project. Then in third_party directory create subdirectories called andengine and andenginebox2d. I assume that you already downloaded or cloned AndEngine and Box2d extension for it. Put AndEngine and AndEngineBox2d in andengine and andenginebox2d directories respectively. Create file named build.gradle in andengine directory and andenginebox2d directory. Build.gradle files is a file that tells gradle how to build your project.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Open settings.gradle that is located in your project's root directory and add two lines to it:

```
include ':third_party:andengine'
include ':third_party:andenginebox2d'
```

Next open build.gradle which locates in app directory and add

```
compile project(':third_party:andengine')
```

The final step is to open AndroidManifest.xml in andegine and andenginebox2d directories and make them look like this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.andengine">

<application>
</application>
</manifest>
```

application  block is needed because of bug in manifest merging tool.
That's it! Now clean your project and press run. Everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

As the question's answers havn't been accepted yet, and I know people are still searching for solutions to this, I found this great website with very very clear and concise instructions to import AndEngine to your Android Studio projects. Here's the link:

http://geq-i.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-setup-andengine-in-android-studio.html

All credits go to the user who created this page. I can attest to the fact that this is working perfectly. I JUST used this website after trying 10s of different ways.
Only thing to note on the link is the last part:

```
$ cd <project folder>/AndEngine/src/main
$ rm -r java/org
$ mv org java
```

This part is copying the org folder from `.` to `./main/java`. Best way to do this is to just drag and drop the org folder into main/java when the project has finished building once.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Well i had the same problem - This helped me to solve it.
 http://www.makethegame.net/android-andengine/how-to-setup-andengine-with-android-studio/

Comment: this is the best answer why to bother with copying rsyncing files by yourself if there's a huge menu itom called import seriously cannot understand the reason in previous answers