# Adding AndEngine to an existing AndroidStudio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine

I am encountering this error, and I have not been able to find an effective tutorial to import AndEngine into my Android Studio project. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add AndEngine to Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079288/unable-to-add-andengine-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a jar file of andengine then simply follow these steps

1. open project in project view
2. copy jar file into libs folder
3. right click on jar file and select add as library

Answer (score 0):

On `AndroidStudio` you can add a library from maven or adding it in the dependecies.

So, that library you said, doesn't have maven link or etc.

It's just have a `Eclipse` project which you need to add it in your `AndroidStudio` like this:

`Andengine`

Just select the root folder not the activities or that `/org/` path.

**Check this link:** http://www.makethegame.net/android-andengine/how-to-setup-andengine-with-android-studio/